# bringToFront issue in android

Tags: java, android

I am using bringToFront in one of my android application. I am not able to make it working as my requirement. There id with paint_view and rearrangeable_layout is working fine whenever I want but even I call id `sticker_view` to bring front....its come in front but `paint_view1` also stay in front and I am able to draw. I want keep `paint_view1` to behind `sticker_view`.
My XML for view is like below

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/admob"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnr_draw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:visibility="visible">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <com.example.myclass.cardmaker.PaintView
                    android:id="@+id/paint_view1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView

                    android:id="@+id/sticker_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/sticker_transparent_background"
                    app:borderAlpha="123"
                    app:borderColor="@android:color/black"
                    app:bringToFrontCurrentSticker="true"
                    app:showBorder="true"
                    app:showIcons="true">

                </com.xiaopo.flying.sticker.StickerView>

                <me.panavtec.drawableview.DrawableView
                    android:id="@+id/paintView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_bg"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient14"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


                <com.rajasharan.layout.RearrangeableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rearrangeable_layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    app:outlineColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:selectionZoom="1.2"
                    app:outlineWidth="2dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:padding="@dimen/lblTime"
                            android:id="@+id/text_quotes"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:shadowRadius="0"
                            android:text="Text"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/newMainText" />

                    </RelativeLayout>


                </com.rajasharan.layout.RearrangeableLayout>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:tint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_but_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_text_margin"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_new_edit" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

My Java code for call `bringToFront` is like below

```
stickerView.bringToFront();
stickerView.invalidate();
```

Let me know someone can help me to solve my issue. Thanks